# store multiple records into variable without using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table structure like as :

```
desc temp_table ;
Name                       Null?    Type

student_name                        VARCHAR2(500)
Is_delete                           NUMBER(2)
```

using pl sql procedure I'm trying to store all values of above table into a variable.

If table has more then one row then I'm getting error like

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

So without using cursor how can we store multiple row's in a variable??

Comment: Do you want to store count of student_name into NumberOfNames?

Comment: want to store actual names of student not count(*) @hkutluay

Comment: You need to [bulk collect the information into a collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html). I'm not sure why you want to avoid a cursor, when that's what is providing the information you want to store? What is it you're actually going to do with the data? Insert it somewhere? Pass it out to another procedure? (The latter two would mean a different solution would be better for your purpose.)

Comment: after few lookup's in some other tables ...i have to pass this result to some other procedure.bulk collect didn't worked for me ...may be because i'm storing only 20-30 values into a variable @Boneist

Comment: Sounds like you need to pass this to your other procedure as a ref cursor, then. Or maybe just use it as a cursor in that other procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Define two collection types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BooleanList IS TABLE OF NUMBER(1,0);
/
```

Use `BULK COLLECT INTO`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_TABLE
AS
  Names StringList;
  Del   BooleanList;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
  SELECT student_name,
         Is_delete
  BULK COLLECT INTO
         Names,
         Del
  FROM   temp_table
  WHERE  MODIFIED_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
  AND    MODIFIED_DATE <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number Of Names: ' || Names.COUNT );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number Of Del: ' || Del.COUNT ); -- Will always be the same amount

  FOR i IN 1 .. Names.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( Names(i) || ', ' || Del(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```